# CSS Content Text disappeared but works on mobile

Tags: html, css

Trying to troubleshoot an old developers work...our titles on our company website [Link Here](http://neriumskincare.com/about/) the CSS content is not showing up only the bordered line. On mobile it looks to be fine though.

hr.aboutUs { padding: 0; border: none; border-top: 1px solid #808080; color: #808080; text-align: center; }

hr.aboutUs::after { content: "About Us"; display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -0.7em; font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 0.75em; background: white; }

***Its showing on Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to declare the `hr.aboutUs:after` in a media query that targets desktop devices.

```
@media all and (max-width: 806px) {
    hr.aboutUs:after {
        content: "About Us";
        display: inline-block;
        top: 1.5em;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 0.75em;
        background: white;
        z-index: 10000;
        position: absolute;
        left: 22.5em;
    }
}
```

Make sure this is added after line #589.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Jayman! I got it to work with this `@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1400px){
    hr.aboutUs:after {
        content: "About Us";
        display: inline-block;
        top: 1.5em;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0 0.75em;
        background: white;
        z-index: 10000;
        position: absolute;
        left: 37%;
        right: 37%;
    }
}`

Comment: Figured out the issue for anyone who has the same issue...I needed to add overflow: visible;